# How much RAM or CPU configuration is required for good rendering

Tags: rendering, 3dsmax

I am learning 3ds max . I was just wodering if need to build a complete small village with small building , hotels , rooms , then do i need more advanced configuration . i mean how much minimum RAM will be required for to make the walk through of whole village

I am new bie so i have no idea . i mean do everything has to be in one max file  or i need to make them separate then put in one scene . i am confused

Answer (score 3):

How large is the village?  How many polygons?  How many textures?  There are a lot of details left out.

Personally, in such a situation, I'd start with simple terrain rendering. Get the land working first.  Second, make a single building.  Get it loaded into the world and placed.  Repeat step 2 until you have a village.  If you're looking at being able to transition inside buildings, then you're opening up a whole new set of issues.  How much detail is inside?  Is a separate loading transition acceptable?  Would a portal system work for that?

Third, get terrain material transitions working (road->grass->dirt).

Comment: I am just learning max , but my main project is to build a coomplete viallge like 50 buildings , hospitals , parks . i would also like to go inside few buildings . i just wanted to know whether i will be able to do it on my PC or not. There are ready made mx files for buildings , hospitals but they are 50MB each . Can import 100s of those in one file

Comment: Within 3ds Max, yes... Sort of. I've done some very, very large modeling with xrefs (Externally referenced files). When loading back into a game though this will get problematic.  To use xref (been ages, from memory), you model individual pieces in separate files.  In your master scene, you can load that file as an XRef - it loads a low-poly representation of the larger to keep the scene fast to work in.  Again though, this is ONLY in max - not your game.  The real question of being able to load the whole Max scene into your game is very, very different.

Comment: Info on XRef: whole scene: http://www.3dmax-tutorials.com/XRef_Scenes.html Object: http://www.3dmax-tutorials.com/XRef_Objects.html  I still argue that you'll have better luck assembling the scene from individual components in game rather than trying to take a huge Max scene into the game.

Comment: Final note: You can also stick particular pieces together in layers and turn them on/off as needed to keep performance in Max high (layer for terrain details, one for trees, one for signs, etc..)

Comment: thanks for the info buddy , but i am not into games . i just want to create walk throughs and animation

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed you're asking a lot of questions that are getting negative or zero votes, and they seem to be related to modeling. I don't know if it is a language barrier, but people here find your questions difficult to answer or somewhat off-topic.

To answer the title question directly, a modern CPU with a reasonable amount of RAM, say 1-2GB is more than sufficient. You can always check the modeling program's minimum requirements and go up from there. However, judging by the questions you ask, I think you need to spend less time asking "How much RAM or CPU configuration is required for good rendering", "Should i learn 3ds max or maya", "Should i learn 3ds max or maya", or "How much time it will take to learn 3ds Max", and just pick something and do it. Don't focus so much on the prerequisites of learning -- cut straight to the learning and doing.

Truth be told, you can use a Pentium III with a GeForce4 to model a small village if you did it in something like Wings3D. Is it ideal? For most people, probably not. Is it doable? Yes, very likely.
Having a computer with more RAM/faster CPU/"Super3D Package 2011" won't make you better at modeling or learn the skills, which you seem to want to build up.

It's going to take time, blood, sweat, and tears, not computing hardware, to build a small village. Spend some time learning your programs, reading tutorials, and becoming a master of your modeling environment -- worry about your computer later. I think you'll find mundane (and mostly irrelevant) questions like "one file or many scenes" to be answered as you gain experience with you program of choice. I'd imagine the answers have a lot less to do with computer hardware and more to do with manageability and project scope.

Comment: thanks for answering my questions. i have always learned so much in my life by just asking questions. Even though i look like fool to someone but i don't care. As long as i am not harming anyone i am satisfied. You won't beleive it in all forums  so many times i got -ve votes , but i leanred so much from those questions. They made by base. because there are always people like you ,who answer and i get knowledge. my teacher always told me to ask question no matter what other think of you. if someone don't like , they have option not to answer and give -ve vote. i asked what i wanted to know